# Changing name of directory containing read-only files

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I am trying to get this script to work, it gets 4 arguments and ends renaming the the folder (FDirectory) removing spaces and starting a batch file with the new arguments. The problem is that it returns an error "access denied" for folders containing read-only files. Is there a way to get this to work? Thanks in advance.

```
  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  currentDirectory = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(len(WScript.ScriptName)))
  length = Len(currentDirectory)

  State = WScript.Arguments.item(0)
  Directory = Left(WScript.Arguments.item(1),length+6)
  FDirectory = Replace(WScript.Arguments.item(1)," ",".")
  Kind = WScript.Arguments.item(2)
  Message = WScript.Arguments.item(3)

  'change folder name
  If (kind = "multi") And (Directory = currentDirectory & "SFetch") then
  Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  FS.MoveFolder WScript.Arguments.item(1),Replace(WScript.Arguments.item(1)," ",".")
  END IF

  currentDirectory = currentDirectory & "Rename.bat "

  WshShell.RUN currentDirectory & State & " " & Directory & " " & FDirectory & " " & Kind & " " & Message, 0, True
  Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read-only files don't create an issue - but renaming a folder with open files inside it, or renaming the current working directory will create problems.